# Как справить ошибку в wing Debugger: nothing to debug. File does not exist при попытке откладки

Tags: python, отладка, ide

Пользуюсь IDE для питона Wing. Все было хорошо, но теперь при попытке откладки, выскакивает такая ошибка:
"Debugger: nothing to debug
File doesn't exist: <имя файла> <путь файла>".
Я создал такой файл, ошибка пропала, но при попытке откладки любого другого файла, он открывает этот и начинает откладывать его. ЧТо делать? я переустановил сам IDE, но ошибка никуда не делась.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте удалить и WingIDE и Pthon. Потом установить в таком порядке: Python, а затем Wing IDE. Еще при установке попробуйте добавить пути в переменную PATH